# JupyterHub fails to spawn new session with 'No module named IPythonHandler'

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am using the jupyterhub 1.4 Docker image and have set it up to spawn sessions with sudospawner-singleuser. However I now get the following error when a user tries to log in:

`AttributeError: module 'notebook.base.handlers' has no attribute 'IPythonHandler'`

The setup used to work but started to fail after I restarted my container. I also tried the 1.5 image and got the same error, both with the following stack trace:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/traitlets/utils/importstring.py", line 32, in import_item
     pak = getattr(module, obj)
 AttributeError: module 'notebook.base.handlers' has no attribute 'IPythonHandler'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jupyterlab/labhubapp.py", line 19, in <module>
     from jupyterhub.singleuser.mixins import make_singleuser_app
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
     from .app import main
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser/app.py", line 41, in <module>
     SingleUserNotebookApp = make_singleuser_app(App)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser/mixins.py", line 916, in make_singleuser_app
     BaseHandler = _patch_app_base_handlers(empty_parent_app)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser/mixins.py", line 871, in _patch_app_base_handlers
     base_handlers.append(import_item(base_handler_name))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/traitlets/utils/importstring.py", line 34, in import_item
     raise ImportError("No module named %s" % obj)
 ImportError: No module named IPythonHandler
```

Any idea why this is now happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try downgrading module nbclassic to 0.3.7 and restart jupyterhub server

```
pip install nbclassic==0.3.7
```

Comment: How did you know it was this module?

Answer (score 0):

I had a working(old) deployment of jupyterhub server. I check pip list for both servers and found version differences for some python modules. nbclassic module was fresh(and some other modules too, but hey did not affect the server) on nonworking server.

I checked nbclassic and the new version was released yesterday:
https://github.com/jupyter/nbclassic/commits/main
I downgraded the module and it worked for me.